# How to group key:value pairs in a python dictionary based on certain range or interval?

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram

I have a dictionary `dict={14:1, 15:2, 16:4, 11:5, 20:1,22:5,25:2...}` in python

How can I obtain a final result in any data structure(dictionary or something else) which looks like:

`Final= [10-15:8, 16-20:5, 21-25:7....]` or at least can sum up the values for keys falling under certain ranges of let say 10-15, 15-20 etc.

The final goal is to containerize data for building histogram or bar graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

my_dict = {14:1, 15:2, 16:4, 11:5, 20:1, 22:5, 25:2}
key_fn, result = lambda (x, _): x / 5 + 1  if x % 5 else x / 5, {}

for item, grp in groupby(sorted(my_dict.items(), key = key_fn), key_fn):
    result[((item - 1) * 5 + 1, item * 5)] = sum(count for _, count in grp)

print result
```

**Output**

```
{(11, 15): 8, (21, 25): 7, (16, 20): 5}
```

Comment: +1: The only concern is, the ranges are out of order, but else nice solution

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I tried all the methods and all of them worked. You guys are great!

Answer (score 1):

What about using `modulo` and `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(int)
input = {14:1, 15:2, 16:4, 11:5, 20:1, 22:5, 25:2}
group = 5

for key, value in input.iteritems():
    output[key - key % group] += value

>> {25: 2, 10: 6, 20: 6, 15: 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) after flattening your dictionary

**Implementation**

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain
data={14:1, 15:2, 16:4, 11:5, 20:1,22:5,25:2}
#Flattern your dictionary
data = list(chain.from_iterable([k]*v for k, v in data.items()))
#Define your bins
bins = [10,16,21,25]
And finally generate the histogram
hist = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)[0]
```

**Output**

```
for r in zip(bins, bins[1:], hist):
    print "{}-{}:{}".format(*r)


10-16:8
16-21:5
21-25:7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got:

```
newdict = {}
for key, value in dict.items:
    mapped_key = key / 5  # if python 2
    mapped key = key // 5 # if python 3
    newdict.setdefault(mapped_key, 0)
    newdict[mapped_key] += value
```

Now someone will go and one-up me with a single-line crazy map lambda dictionary comprehenshion thing.